# boot failure after upgrade ubuntu 12.04

Tags: 12.04, upgrade, xserver

My laptop cannot boot up after I upgrade ubuntu 12.04. The error message is
unsupported number of auguments (3) back to default xsession

Anyone have solution to this problem?

Answer (score 1):

That looks more that your xserver is not starting instead of your whole server. Isn't it?

Do you get a shell? What do you see on your screen?

Try

```
 dpgk-reconfigure xserver-xorg
```

to reconfigure your xserver.

Have a look in your logfiles

```
 tail -200 /var/log/syslog
```

or

```
tail -200 /var/log/Xorg.0.log
```

for any hints what exactly is going wrong.